# AutoHotKey sporadic mouse movement behavior in particular program with Click/MoveMouse

Tags: autohotkey

I made a quick ahk script that moved the mouse and found that the mouse wasn't getting moved to the desired location. I set up a loop that continually moved the cursor to the same position every couple of seconds, and the mouse would be moved to different, seemingly-random positions instead. I found that this was only the case with a specific program's window focused and if I had any other program focused the mouse moved as expected. I tried using Click/MouseMove, and they both exhibited this behavior. I also tried DllCall("SetCursorPosition"), but that wouldn't even move the mouse. Just to further clarify, all three of those worked fine when the problem program wasn't focused -- I only had issues when the problem program was focused.

Upon further inspection, this seemed to be due to the program's custom mouse sensitivity implementation. If I used MouseMove to move the cursor 1 pixel down relative to the current position, it'd move down ~50. If I increased the program's mouse sensitivity, it'd move down even further. I assume this is also why I was getting seemingly-random mouse positions with Click.

For now I've implemented a custom click function which unfocuses the program, moves the mouse, re-focuses the program, and then clicks, but the program doesn't like that. Sometimes it works, but sometimes the program will ignore mouse clicks from the position the mouse was when the window was focused, leading to the script not being able to do the things I want it to be able to do.

Is there a way for me to take into account this program's mouse sensitivity while using Click x,y/MouseMove? Or maybe an alternative method of moving the mouse that isn't affected by the program's mouse sensitivity. I've tried using all types of CoordMode, but all of them have the same problem.

Edit: Script I'm using

```
CoordMode, Mouse,Screen ; I've tried every CoordMode but none solve the problem

AppsKey::
    while true {
        Click 500,500,0
        sleep,2000
    }
Return
```

Comment: Your question is massive in proportions. Too much reading, too slightly spaced. Keep things short, elaborate only when you have to.

Comment: It can't be made any shorter without removing relevant information.

Comment: Is the mouse "moving" part actually important or do you just need to click certain on positions?

Answer (score 0):

Or, it could be that you are not making use of `CoordMode`, and by default when you don't specify this, unfortunately mouse positions are reliant on the active window, which can cause unpredictable results as you discovered. For more reliability, I like to always precede my mouse movement commands with this command that sets the coordinate system of the mouse to the refer to the screen instead:

```
CoordMode, Mouse
```

### Explanation

Documentation about [CoordMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm):

> If this command is not used, all commands except those documented otherwise (e.g. WinMove and InputBox) use coordinates that are relative to the active window.

The full command is

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
```

But documentation says we can omit the second parameter and it defaults to Screen:

> If Param2 is omitted, it defaults to Screen.

So for more consistent results, use `CoordMode` command.

Comment: At the bottom of the original post I mentioned that I've tried every single CoordMode and they all result in the same problem. Just in case the issue was AHK was resetting it after I changed it once at the top of the script, I just tried setting the CoordMode immediately before moving the mouse, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: My apologies, I see now you do mention it, though it didn't have specific placement until your comment so I'll leave this answer in case it helps others with CoordMode issues. Also, is it possible to see the current working code you came up with, plus the last code(s) you tried with `CoordMode, Mouse`? Also, in case the code doesn't reveal this, what program is this that can interfere with mouse behavior? It might lead to more clues, Thanks

Comment: Edited the script I'm using in its entirety into the OP. The program in question is the game client for [ROBLOX](http://www.roblox.com), a free UGC gaming platform. If you're looking to test it yourself, you'll need to press the AppsKey without the client window focused and tab into it afterwards because the ROBLOX client is one of those evil programs that likes to steal all keyboard/mouse input.

Comment: I see your updated code, have you tried to get more consistent results by putting the CoordMode... line within the AppsKey , definition meaning, right after `AppsKey::`  line?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to help if setting the CoordMode immediately before moving the mouse didn't work, but I tried it anyway. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with SendPlay (but see below if you use UAC):

```
AppsKey::
    while true {
        SetMouseDelay, 20, Play  ;  or play around with the delay amt
        sleep, 50  ;  or play around with the sleep amt
        SendPlay {Click 500,500,0}
        sleep, 50  ;  or play around with the sleep amt
        SetMouseDelay, 0
        sleep,2000
    }
Return
```

**SendPlay [v1.0.43+]**

SendPlay's biggest advantage is its ability to "play back" keystrokes and mouse clicks in a broader variety of games than the other modes. For example, a particular game may accept hotstrings only when they have the SendPlay option. However, SendPlay may have no effect at all on Windows Vista or later if User Account Control is enabled, even if the script is running as an administrator. The following script provides a workaround for this problem: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic75595.html.

Of the three sending modes, SendPlay is the most unusual because it does not simulate keystrokes and mouse clicks per se. Instead, it creates a series of events (messages) that flow directly to the active window (similar to ControlSend, but at a lower level). Consequently, SendPlay does not trigger hotkeys or hotstrings.